# JS Get Input Value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the value of an input text field, so I can have a SQL query to change its password. For some reason using the default values provided on the JQuery website e.g. name = "John", time = "2pm". I want to send two strings to get changed, but for some reason A) there is no error or B) any idea if it actually makes it to the test file. Any help would be great!

```js
$("#password_change").submit(function(event) {
  var $form = "#password_change";
  $collar = $form.find("input[name='collar']").val(),

    $.post("test.php", {
      name: $collar,
      time: "2pm"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the second line of code: var $form = $("#password_change");  ?

Comment: You should be getting an error from `$form.find()` since `$form` is a string and it has no `.find()` method.

Comment: You should declare `$collar` as a local variable. And the assignment should end with `;`, not `,`

Comment: Added a semi colon to the end $collar. Not getting any errors in the console for the $form, how would I add .find()?
Console: https://gyazo.com/ee41938120a0a670fc2e4d4b4f211aea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$("#password_change").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var $form = $(this);
  var dt = new Date();
  var hour = dt.getHours();
  var mer = (hour > 11 ? "PM" : "AM");

  if (hour > 11 && hour != 12) {
    hour = hour - 12;
  }

  var $collar = $("input[name='collar']", $form).val();
  var myData = {
    name: $collar,
    time: hour + mer
  };
  console.log(myData);

  /*
  $.post("test.php", myData)
    .done(function(data) {
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
  });
  */
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="password_change">
  <input name="collar" type="hidden" value="Tim" />
  <input type="password" placeholder="New Password" />
</form>
```

You will want to `preventDefault()` on the Form Submission. This ensures it does not try to submit the data regularly.

A few minor changes to help improve the script.

Comment: So I would just use   var $collar = $("input[name='collar']", $form).val(); and
  var $collar = $("input[name='password']", $form).val(); to then send it through the AJAX POST function?

Comment: @Welshy1235 you can use those but I would use unique variable names.

Comment: Tried doing it, didn't work

Comment: @Welshy1235 Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Apologies, you were correct. I just jumped the gun and messed up a little on my end. Thanks so much for the help!